# jQuery selection and slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got html like this :

```
<div id=1 class=header onclick="hideit(this.id)">Header1
<div class=content>Some content
</div>
</div>
```

There are lots of this structure used in my code I want wo toggle the second div (content) if someone clicks on the header.

I wrote this function but its not working, can anybody tell me why?

```
<script language="javascript">
    function hideit(hID)
    {
      var searcher = "div[id="+hID+"] .content";
      $(searcher).slideToggle();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot start your id with a number.  Please see answers below that mention this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery, there is really no need to call a function inline. You can accomplish what you are trying to do with this simple event handler:

```
$(".header").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".content").slideToggle();
});
```

Also, element IDs should not start with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
# is the selector for ids
```

so in your case

```
div#1 .content
```

Comment: Ha, you know placing a '#' sign in front of your text makes it a header right? So your first comment is meant to be, `# is the selector for Id's`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally those "structures" share a common parent node. If there are a lot of those, it's best practice to use event delegation. Lets assume there is a `<div>` with the id `foo` which contains all of those constructs:

```
$('#foo').delegate('div.header', 'click', function( event ) {
    $(this).find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

This will bind *one* event handler to the shared parent node. If there isn't a common parent node, you would need to bind an event handler for each of your `.header` div elements:

```
$('.header').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideit(hID)  {
    $('#'+hID).find('.content).slideToggle();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="1" class="header">Header1
    <div class="content">Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".header").click(function() {
    $(".content", $(this)).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. while your id attribute can be numerical in HTML5 I would still strongly suggest against using a digit to start your id. Perhaps id-1,
2. I would do it as follows

**jquery/javascripit**

```
$(function(){ 
      ('div.header').click(function() {
         $('div.content', this).slideToggle(); });`
)};
```

**html**

```
<div id='id-1' class='header'>Header1
  <div class='content'>Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/QSvYE/

if you chose to go the route of selecting by id # perhaps the following regex would be helpful

```
//set regex
var re = /(^\w+-)(\d+)$/i;

//get attr broken into parts
var str = $(this).attr('id').match(re)[1], 
    id  = $(this).attr('id').match(re)[2];
```